# Google Cloud Datastore - Is it possible to update entities without downloading them before?

Tags: cloud, datastore

I would like to add new data / manipulate data in already existing google cloud datastore entities. Is that possible without the need to fetch/manipuate/update the entities? I heard that mongodb supports this operation, so I wonder that I cannot find anything about that in the datastore documentation.

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned in [Google Cloud Datastore Best Practice Documentation](https://cloud.google.com/datastore/docs/best-practices)

A single entity group in Cloud Datastore should not be updated too rapidly.

If you are using Cloud Datastore, Google recommends that you design your application so that it will not need to update an entity group more than once per second. Remember that an entity with no parent and no children is its own entity group. If you update an entity group too rapidly then your Cloud Datastore writes will have higher latency, timeouts, and other types of error. This is known as contention.

Cloud Datastore write rates to a single entity group can sometimes exceed the one per second limit so load tests might not show this problem. Some suggestions for designing your application to reduce write rates on entity groups are in the Cloud Datastore contention article.